# Редирект с index.html на /

Tags: apache, php, html, javascript

Всем привет, подскажите как сделать редирект с [www.mysite.ru/index.html](http://www.mysite.ru/index.html) на [www.mysite.ru/](http://www.mysite.ru/) ?делаю так, но не работает, в чем ошибка?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ \/index\.html\ HTTP\/
RewriteRule /index\.html$ /
```

Comment: так "/" и означает корень сайта который в зависимости от настроек апача запустит индексный файл. Зачем тебе с индекса на индекс? или я чтото не то понял?

Comment: проще говоря мне нужно чтобы вместо www.mysite.ru/index.php открывалась ссылка www.mysite.ru/

Comment: по умолчанию апач запускает index. У тебя я так понял есть и пхп и хтмл индексы. Тут все говорит само за себя - переименуй тот который не нужен, либо удали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DirectoryIndex /
RewriteEngine On
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirect permanent /index.php http://altairplus.ru/
```